# "would have had" vs "should have"

Tags: conditional-constructions

Are these two sentences grammatical and equivalent?

> 1 If I had not taken my phone there, I would have had to go back home, pick it up, and take it there.

> 2 If I had not taken my phone there, I should have gone back home, picked it up, and taken it there.

Comment: "...I would have had to go back home and fetch it." It sounds odd to say "If I had not taken it, I would have had to... take it".

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks I wasn't familiar with the word "fetch". I was somehow looking for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Question 1*

Are the sentences grammatical?

*Answer*

Yes, they are.

---

*Question 2*

Are they equivalent?

*Answer*

No, they are not. Saying what one **would do** is not the same as saying what one **should do**.

---

**Examples**

1. I *shouldn't* eat fatty and sugary foods, but I *would* do so anyway.
2. I *should* exercise, but I *won't*.

Answer (score -1):

The correct one is the first sentence, since "I should have gone" has a meaning of regret.